# pgfplots: "minor y tick num" not working as expected (not showing)

Tags: pgfplots

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\section*{\texttt{minor y tick num} Works}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    %
    axis x line = bottom,
    axis y line = left, 
    %
    grid = both,
    minor x tick num = 1,
    minor y tick num = 1,
    %
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 10.2,
    xtick = {0,1,...,10},
    %
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 1.05,    
    %
    ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\section*{\texttt{minor y tick num} Does Not Work}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    % 
    axis x line = bottom,
    axis y line = left, 
    %   
    grid = both,
    minor x tick num = 1,
    minor y tick num = 1,
    %               
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 10.2,
    xtick = {0,1,...,10},
    %   
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 1.05,
    ytick = {0,0.2,...,1.2}, % <--- Difference
    %           
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> **Problem**
>   As soon as I define `ytick = {0,0.2,...,1.2},` the *minor y ticks*
>   *disappear*. Maybe I don't see the obvious :=).

[image]

Comment: This has been asked before once as far as I can remember. The problem is that `0,0.2,...,1.2` doesn't give you exactly 0.2 between the ticks due to to numerical imprecisions, that is you might get one tick at 0.2, the next at 0.4, but the next after that at 0.599999. Minor ticks are only added if the major ticks have the same distance. Use `ytick = {0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2},` and you get minor ticks.

Comment: Or use `ytick distance=0.2`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks a lot. Very tricky that tick problem.